# (C#) Can I programmatically set an XLSX cell to a picture/image?

Tags: c#, excel, epplus

I am hoping to make spreadsheets that contain some pictures (embed pictures from files) and I started looking at [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/) (looks like a great library)

However it seems that the images are not tied to a cell - rather to an x,y, coordinate.

Is there a way with EPPlus or other way to set a cell to a picture (and then manipulate the size of the cell?)

SetPosition

Comment: not sure why this was downvoted.

Comment: It seems in normal excel you can place a bitmap image on a cell and then allow it to be resized with the cell ( format picture -> options -> properties ). You might be able to simulate placing an image in a cell using this but i doubt you can use it any more than that

Comment: @IanNorton - ok, thanks.  Perhaps it is my misunderstanding of the use.  EPPlus seems like the way to go in any case.

Comment: I did find a reference somewhere that points out I can add a comment for a cell, then add a picture to a comment.

Comment: @Tim, Can you share that reference? I am trying to add an image to a comment.. Thank you!

Comment: @ntsue - see my answer below.  Note that this does NOT explain how to do it programmatically - it is just more background about what pictures are "tied to"  http://blog.mclaughlinsoftware.com/microsoft-excel/add-image-to-a-comment/

Comment: @Tim, Thanks! I saw that article before though, I am just trying to do it programmatically now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can insert the picture, then adjust its `.Top` and `.Left` so it aligns with the `.Top` and `.Left` of the appropriate cell. You can set the `.RowHeight` of the cell's row using the same units as the `.height` of the picture (though there's a maximum height). The `.ColumnWidth` of the column is in units of text characters wide, so what I do is something like:

```
myColumn.ColumnWidth = myColumn.ColumnWidth / myColumn.Width * myPicture.Width
```

and I run it twice because sometimes the first time you set `.ColumnWidth`, it isn't set precisely.

Answer (score 5):

My misunderstanding...

Here is a comment I found when looking around:

> No version of Excel allows you to insert a picture into a cell. Pictures are inserted into the worksheet and will always float.
>   One of the properties of a picture can be set to "move and size with cells" but that only moves or stretches the picture when the underlying rows and columns are inserted, deleted or sized. It does not confine a picture to a cell.

So perhaps I just need to set the properties appropriately.

If I can [do this programmatically](http://blog.mclaughlinsoftware.com/microsoft-excel/add-image-to-a-comment/) I will be all set

**EDIT**

The following code does pretty much what I want/need.

Note that before inserting the pics I set the width and height of the cell I was overlaying to appropriate sizes.

```
private static void AddImage(ExcelWorksheet ws, int rowIndex, String imageFile)
{
    ExcelPicture picture = null;
    Bitmap image = new Bitmap(imageFile);

    if (image != null)
    {
        picture = ws.Drawings.AddPicture("pic" + rowIndex.ToString(), image);                
        picture.From.Column = 0;
        picture.From.Row = rowIndex-1;
        picture.SetSize(320, 240);
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, is it possible to set to "move and size with cells" property in EPPlus? the reason I ask this is after client generate the excel, they need to filter the record, everything works fine except image, because all images are overlapping under the first record image.

Comment: Vincent, did you ever figure out how to do that? I'm looking for it too, but with no luck.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do that in Excel itself; when you add a picture to an Excel worksheet, it's a floating object, it's not fixed to a specific cell.

Answer (score 0):

Found in the `EPPLUS` documentation it should be possible with the `EditAs` setting on value `TwoCell`.

```
picture.EditAs = eEditAs.TwoCell;
```

"Specifies that the current drawing shall move and resize to maintain its row and column anchors (i.e. the object is anchored to the actual from and to row and column). "