# How can I programmatically set images to move and size with cells?

Tags: c#, excel, epplus

You can change how an image is affected by resizing columns and rows in Excel by right clicking the image, clicking "Size and Properties", and then selecting "Properties". By default, it is "Move but don't size with cells". I want to programmatically set images to "Move and size with cells" using EPPlus. If that's not possible, is it possible to change it to "Move and size with cells" for all images on the sheet?

Here's the code that inserts each image:

```
System.Drawing.Image thumbnail = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(imagePath);                            
var picture = worksheet.Drawings.AddPicture(data, thumbnail);
picture.SetSize(65, 20);                            
picture.SetPosition(j - 1, 0, 3 + x++, 0);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [(C#) Can I programmatically set an XLSX cell to a picture/image?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7475787/c-can-i-programmatically-set-an-xlsx-cell-to-a-picture-image)

Comment: Not the same question. The answers posted insert the image so that it fills the cell, but once the spreadsheet is made and saved, changing column/row sizes will not affect the image. One of the answers (Tim's) mentions what I am looking for, but does not actually solve it. Vincent then comments on that answer asking essentially the question that I am asking now. But Vincent is never responded to. :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set the picture to `TwoCell` in the `EditAs` setting:

```
picture.EditAs = eEditAs.TwoCell;
```

This will tell excel to stretch it.